# Loaded Entity has parent but has no @Parent

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have the following schema, using Objectify

```
@Entity
public class Book{
  @Id
  private long id;
  private Key<Page> pages;
  …

}

@Entity 
public class Page{
  @Id
  private String id;
  …

  public Page(Book book,int pageNumber){
    this.id = book.getId()+””+pageNumber;
     …
  }

}
```

I am getting the complaint

> com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading
>   Book(1401058017250)/Page("14010580172505639445604728832"): Loaded
>   Entity has parent but com.company.api.db.Page has no @Parent
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Loaded Entity has parent
>   but com.company.api.db.Page has no @Parent

I am coming from Eclipse and Datanucleus and in that framework the code was

```
@Entity
public class Book{
  @Id
  private long id;
  private List<Page> pages;
  …

}

@Entity 
public class Page{
  @Id
  private Key key;
  …

  public Page(Book book,int pageNumber){
    this.key = createKey(book.getId(),pageNumber);
     …
  }

private Key createKey(long bookId, long pageNumber) {
    Key bookKey = KeyFactory.createKey(Book.class.getSimpleName(), bookId);
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(bookKey, Page.class.getSimpleName(), bookId + "" + pageNumber);
    return key;
  }

}
```

Whether it was the best code or not, it used to work. So anyway, I am migrating to Objectify and Android Studio. How do I rewrite this schema so I stop getting the error? If someone does know the answer, please just copy and paste my code snippet and make the appropriate edits.

Answer (score 1):

In your old code, you're marking bookKey as the parent entity. In new code, you need to have:

```
@Parent
Key<Book> parentBook;
```

Your new classes should be:

```
@Entity
public class Book{
  @Id
  private long id;
  private List<Key<Page>> pages;
  …
}

@Entity 
public class Page{
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Parent
  Key<Book> parentBook;
  …

  public Page(long bookId, int pageNumber){
    this.id = bookId + ”” +pageNumber;
    this.parentBook = Key.create(Book.class, bookId);
     …
  }

}
```

Read more about Keys and objectify here: https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Keys

Comment: I think it works. +1. But right now some other stuff are failing. So I have to wait to be certain.